# CiviVolunteer - Volunteers who register through an Event page don't have Contact type set to Volunteer

Tags: civivolunteer

Using Wordpress 4.7.2, CiviCRM 4.7.15 with CiviVolunteer module version 4.6-2.2.1. Everything seems to be working very well. We have our Volunteer projects and roles setup. I have an event and have turned on Volunteer registration with a specific profile. All good.

The only problem is when a volunteer registers for a shift, the created contact record doesn't have the Contact Type set to is Volunteer. Ideas?